# Node.js is not installing correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Im installing **Node-RED** in Windows 10, following the steps from https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/windows.
I've downloaded the *node-v12.16.3-x64.msi* file from https://nodejs.org/en/ and it installed properly.
When I run the following command in **cmd**
`node --version && npm --version` it returns the following message:

`C:\Users\Arroz>node --version && npm --version
v12.16.3
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
6.14.4`

Then when I run the following command `npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red`, it returns the following message:

```
C:\Users\Arroz>npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\ansi-regex):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\aproba):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.4 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\chownr):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\code-point-at):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\console-control-strings):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: debug@3.2.6 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\debug):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\deep-extend):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\delegates):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: are-we-there-yet@1.1.5 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\are-we-there-yet):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\detect-libc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\has-unicode):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ignore-walk@3.0.3 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\ignore-walk):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\ini):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: nan@2.13.2 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\nan):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: needle@2.4.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\needle):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\node_modules\semver):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-bundled@1.1.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\npm-bundled):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-packlist@1.4.8 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\npm-packlist):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\number-is-nan):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\is-fullwidth-code-point):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: rimraf@2.7.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\rimraf):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\set-blocking):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.3 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\signal-exit):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-ansi@3.0.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\strip-ansi):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: string-width@1.0.2 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\string-width):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\strip-json-comments):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: rc@1.2.8 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\rc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wide-align@1.1.3 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\wide-align):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: gauge@2.7.4 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\gauge):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npmlog@4.1.2 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\npmlog):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\yallist):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minipass@2.9.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\minipass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs-minipass@1.2.7 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\fs-minipass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minizlib@1.3.3 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\minizlib):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: tar@4.4.13 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\tar):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-pre-gyp@0.12.0 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\node-pre-gyp):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bcrypt@3.0.6 (node_modules\node-red\node_modules\bcrypt):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\yourname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\yourname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arroz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-30T15_50_32_619Z-debug.log
```

I have the following **PATH variables**:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32

C:\Users\Arroz\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Program Files\nodejs\

C:\Program Files\Git\bin

I've tried to reinstall **Nodejs**, but it's the same.

Comment: The error is complaining that you do not have permission to write to the `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` to create the `.staging` directory. Have you tried following the instructions at the end of the error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run the same command with cmd as Administrator.

Comment: I have a Virtual Machine with Linux Ubuntu 18.04, so I installed Node.js and Node-RED there and it worked.